# Wait for HTTP response in Service call from component angular 4

Tags: http, synchronization, call

I have created a service which is suppose to invoke http request. My Component is calling that function from ngOnInit(). As the component finishing the call before http gets the request, hence not able to display data on page.

Help is require.
SERVICE:

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class studentsInfoService implements OnInit
{
    _StudentsInfo;
    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){};

    getStudentsList():Observable<any>{
            this.http.get("http://192.168.2.5:81/api/values").subscribe(data=>
            {
                console.log("Invoked getStudentsList :)");
                this._StudentsInfo = data;
                console.log(data);

                return data;
            },err=>{
                console.log("error in getStudentsList");
                return null;
            })
            return this._StudentsInfo;
    }

}
```

component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {studentsInfoService} from '../../Services/studensInfo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-students-info',
  templateUrl: './students-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./students-info.component.css'],
  providers:[studentsInfoService]
})
export class StudentsInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  _sData=null;
  constructor(private sInfoService:studentsInfoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
          let x = this.sInfoService.getStudentsList();
          x.subscribe(x=> this._sData = x);

  }
}
```

Getting error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at StudentsInfoComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app on Component
Help is require to make sync call to service method.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to using the subscribe in the
**this.http.get("http://192.168.2.5:81/api/values").subscribe()**

Use "map" instead of "subscribe" in this, so the code will be such as

```
return this.http.get("http://192.168.2.5:81/api/values").map(
             {
                console.log("Invoked getStudentsList :)");
                this._StudentsInfo = data;
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            },err=>{
                console.log("error in getStudentsList");
                return null;
            })
)
```

Comment: Dear rajagrur, Thanks for the reply. I am unable to find .map method  of http, it is only displaying .subscrib

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/operator/map' this should be added in your service